# Get unique ids from 2 has_many relationships in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, relation, has-and-belongs-to-many

I can't find a simple way to get the ids of pointfields from this relationship

```
pointtype has_and_belongs_to_many pointfields 
pointfield has_and_belongs_to_many pointtypes
```

I do the following :

```
@pointtypes = current_project.points.map{|p| p.pointtype}.uniq
@pointtypes = @pointtypes - [nil]                      # tricky... Is this Railsy ?
@pointfield_ids = @pointtypes.map(&:pointfield_ids)
```

returns

```
 [[16, 17, 18, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [16, 17, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]]
```

and thus

```
@pointfield_ids.uniq!
```

is not working because there is two sub-arrays...

What I need is to get one single array with the unique ids of the pointfields (or the objects itself)

Comment: use pointfield_ids.flatten.uniq!

Comment: also you can use @pointtypes.compact! to remove nil elements

Comment: @pointfields.flatten!.uniq! did the trick :-) (I added a "!" after "flatten")

Comment: ah right. i was thinking that calling .uniq! at the end, it would affect the object but since flatten returns a new record, it wont.